# Add mp4 video on beamer presentation and play the viedo while presenting at Okular

Tags: beamer, overleaf, presentations, video, okular

I am using the following code to embed an mp4 to a beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}


}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}





\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
\section{First Section} % Sections can be created in order to organize your presentation into discrete blocks, all sections and subsections are automatically printed in the table of contents as an overview of the talk
%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Subsection Example} % A subsection can be created just before a set of slides with a common theme to further break down your presentation into chunks

\begin{frame}
\centering
\movie[label=cells,width=5cm,height=4cm,loop,poster,showcontrols]{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{fig2.jpg}}{fig2.mp4}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I am compiling this to overleaf which produces a pdf that I am trying to present in Okular. It;s all good up to the point that I am trying to play the mp4 video which does not open even though it looks like the pdf has a video at this point ( my cursor turns to the usual pointy hand). Could someone help?

*I am trying to present using windows 10!